# How can I determine how many rows were loaded into an EF6 DbContext when using Load/LoadAsync?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

The `DbContext` `DbSet<T>.Load` / `DbSet<T>.LoadAsync` methods return `void` and `Task` respectively: they execute queries and then add the loaded/instantiated entity objects into the `DbContext`'s `DbSet` and update the navigation properties and reverse-navigation of already-loaded objects, but they don't return any information about what they loaded: there doesn't seem to be a way of getting the actual count of the number of rows that were loaded.

Which is surprising, considering that the `SaveChanges` / `SaveChangesAsync` method *does* return the number of rows affected by any DML statements it executes.

I know there's a workaround in that I could use `ToList`/`ToListAsync` instead and then use the `List<T>.Count` property, but that's defeating the point of using `Load`/`LoadAsync`.

---

For example, consider this two-step query operation:

```
async Task<PageViewModel> LoadOrdersAsync( Int32 customerId, Expression<Func<Order,Boolean>> predicate )
{
    // Step 1:
    List<Order> orders = await this.dbContext.Orders
        .Where( o => o.CustomerId == customerId )
        .Where( predicate )
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Step 1.5:
    List<Int32> orderIds = orders.Select( o => o.OrderId ).ToList();

    // Step 2:
    await this.dbContext.OrderItems
        .Where( i => orderIds.Contains( i.OrderId ) )
        .LoadAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Done!
    return new PageViewModel( orders );
}
```

I want to get the quantity of `OrderItem` entities that were loaded in the second step, but as far as I know that isn't possible without using `ToList`/`ToListAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

You’re right, there is no easy way to get the number of loaded entries of the Load. It is essentially the same as ToList without creating the list and adding the loaded elements to it. If you really don’t want to use ToList, one option is to access the DbContext.ChangeTracker and get the number of entries from that:

```cs
var entriesBefore = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count();
// load more entities
var loaded = context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Count() - entriesBefore;
```

Note, that this is not accurate when you include other, related entities in your query.

Comment: I assume I could do something like `changeTracker.Entries().Where( e => e is Order ).Count()` ?

Comment: Yes. When having base and derived classes you might want to use Where(e => e.GetType() == typeof(Order)) which checks for the exact type while is includes any assignable type. When the is operator is the right choice, OfType<Order>() does the same as your query and is a little better to read.

Comment: However, you might be better off just using ToList because it probably performs better than performing a Where on the list, especially when the DbContext caches lots of other entries.